# find path of diskutil

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to find out the path of the diskutil in Cocoa app. In terminal, if I type 'which diskutil', it gives me: '/usr/sbin/diskutil/'. Will it always be this path? If not, how can I programmatically find out the path as I need to use it with NSTask

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `/usr/sbin/diskutil`. If not found, get a list of the paths in $PATH:
`[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"PATH"]`
and look up the command `diskutil` on each of them using the NSFileManager. If the user has access, your application will find it.

An unusual case would be that the command is not on the default system location and the user messed with his PATH. Then you could hardcode a look up in certain locations (/opt/local/bin, /usr/local/bin, ...) or ask the user where it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `env` command do the work for you. Simply say “`env diskutil blah blah blah`”, and `env` will look for `diskutil` in the directories of the user's `PATH` and, if it finds it, run it with the remaining arguments.

For NSTask, this means you'll want to set your task's launch path to `/usr/bin/env`, and its arguments array to the command (`diskutil`) and its arguments; for example, `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"diskutil", @"list", @"-plist", nil]`.

When you run such a task, it will run `env`, and that will `exec` `diskutil` in turn, so you will be indirectly running whatever `diskutil` the `env` program finds without having to find `diskutil` yourself.

You may want to use [PRHTask](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/prhtask/), a replacement for NSTask that I wrote that automates this and some other things. With PRHTask, you can create the `diskutil` task in one line: `[PRHTask taskWithProgramName:@"diskutil" arguments:@"list", @"-plist", nil]`. (You'll still have to run it, of course; there are some other nice features you may want to turn on before you do, detailed on the wiki page.)

Comment: I’m not sure I like this approach: Depending on the user’s environment, the program might end up running a `diskutil` executable that is not necessarily the system `diskutil`. Whilst applications can be moved freely inside the system volume and across volumes, `/usr/bin` is supposed to always be there and replacing `/usr/bin/diskutil` requires administrative privileges.

Comment: @Bavarious: This is true of any solution that searches the search path. The safer but more fragile alternative is to assume that `diskutil` is always in a certain location (currently, `/usr/sbin`, not `/usr/bin`).

Comment: A solution that splits the difference would be to use NSTask (with `env`) or PRHTask, but set `PATH` in the task's environment to a fixed search path of only system directories, such as `@"/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`.